# Toggle's with HashMap, How can it be better?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, toggle

```
public Map<String, Boolean> zoom = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

public void Toggle() {
        if(zoom.containsKey("test")){
            // Turning off
            zoom.remove("test");
        } else {
            // Turning on.
            zoom.put("test", false);
        }
    }
```

I use a HashMap to accomplish it, but i never use the Boolean.
So how can i get rid of the hashmap, without having too much problems?

Comment: change `Map<String, Boolean>` to `Set<String>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
Map<String, Boolean> zoom = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

to

```
Set<String> zoom = new HashSet<String>();
```

Then replace all calls to `put(String, Boolean)` with `add(String)`, calls to `remove` won't change, and calls to `containsKey(String)` are replaced with `contains(String)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! just needed the "new HashSet<String>();" to get it working with sjr solution. Thanks! Brian and sjr!